# Regex expression for: 4 letter words using 'a' to 'e' in lower case

Tags: python, regex

I can manage to get the four letter word from a-z using this `^[a-z]{4}$` But I am not sure how to get it so there is a a and e in in the word. I've tried this but it only gets the worlds with the ae on the end. `^[a-z]{2}[a][e]$`

```
import re
import sys
import time

pattern = '^[a-z]{4}$[a][e]' 

#c = ^[^a][a]{2}

regexp = re.compile(pattern)

inFile = open('words.txt','r')
outFile = open('exercise04.log','w')


for line in inFile:
    match = regexp.search(line)
    if match:
        time.sleep(0.1)
        print(line)
        outFile.write(line)

inFile.close()
outFile.close()
```

Example output from `^[a-z]{2}[a][e]$`

```
alae

blae

brae

frae

spae

thae

twae
```

I i'm looking for random words such as

```
akes
aejs
soae
skea
esao
```

Comment: post some examples for matches.

Comment: Your regex  `^[a-z]{2}[a][e]$` would match the strings you mentioned.

Comment: Is the goal to find a word of four letters precisely, in which exactly one is an `a`, exactly one is an `e`, and the `a` and `e` may appear in any order?

Comment: So there may be more `a`s or `e`s than just one, and they need not be `a` before `e`, as long as both exist?

Comment: @AvinashRaj I'm afriad that doesn't work in the from example above.

Comment: @BRPocock No it just has to be 4 letters and have at least 1 a and 1 e.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use lookahead to check for a line which contains both `a` and `e`

```
^(?=.*?a)(?=.*?e)[a-z]{4}$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/cE4kK2/2)

**Explanation:**

- `^` Start of a line.
- `(?=.*?a)` Positive lookahead asserts that there must be a letter `a` present in that particular line.
- `(?=.*?e)` Positive lookahead asserts that there must be a letter `e` present in that particular  line. Lookarounds usually won't match any characters but it only asserts whether a match is possible or not.
- `[a-z]{4}` Exactly four lowercase letters.
- `$` End of the line anchor.

Comment: Looks like I did the reverse of your solution.

Comment: Brilliant that worked thank you. Is any other way to do this without lookahead? For future reference.

Comment: @jackdh: The other solution in the comment still has look-ahead. A solution without look-ahead would be to list out all ways to have a and e in the length 4 string: `^((ae|ea)[a-z]{2}|[a-z]{2}(ae|ea)|a[a-z]{2}e|e[a-z]{2}a|a[a-z]e[a-z]|e[a-z]a[a-z]|[a-z]a[a-z]e|[a-z]e[a-z]a|[a-z](ae|ea)[a-z])$`

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is: "Find words of exactly four letters, in which there exists at least one `a`, and at least one `e`, in any order", one (faster than regexp, possibly) way to do this is to propose exactly those three questions.

My Python is, um, all but non-existent, but:

```
if 4 == word.length and "a" in word and "e" in word:
```

seems to be a bit less difficult to understand than a regex.

Comment: (Aside: When a "Japh" suggests something that isn't a regex, take note, world.)

Answer (score 0):

A few problems with your original regex '[a-z]{4}$[a][e]'

1. The [a-z] character set has a quantifier of 4 following it, meaning that it will match 4 characters and you were trying to match 2 characters following that.
2. The '$' precedes the other characters you want to match, and the '$' in a regular expression means the end of the line.

If you merely want to match ae at the end you can simply use `[a-z]{2}ae` for a string-literal match.

I generically use word boundaries instead of ^ and $ for beginning and end of line as the word may have whitespace preceding it. Combine that with a positive lookahead for 'ae':

```
\b(?=.*?ae)[a-z]{4}\b
```

Comment: I just tried your solution but it does not limit the character count to 4.

Comment: I will modify my answer with the other examples you provided. I did not see the 4-character restriction.